# How can I remove "Controller" from the names of my controllers in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

So the way MCV3 works is that you define what controller to call though routing. That controller is "myControllerName" + "Controller".

Now that class is already in a folder called controllers. I don't want that decoration on the end of my class names. It's not really contributing anything.

I  want to know how change that and understand more about what goes on inside MVC3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: don't bother. This is *configuration by convention* (also called *convention over configuration*, CoC), and you will live a happier, healthier stress-free life if you just go with the flow, and let MVC do what it wants.

The longer answer is you inject a custom controller factory into the MVC pipeline to override the default one. A full description of the process can be found [in this article](http://keyvan.io/custom-controller-factory-in-asp-net-mvc) but, essentially, you:

1. Implement [`IControllerFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory.aspx) to do whatever you want.
2. In your `Application_Start` event, call [`ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbuilder.setcontrollerfactory.aspx) to replace the default controller factory with your own.

MVC is a highly extensible framework; although the default behavior of most components probably does what you need, you can almost always replace the built-in objects with your own. For other things you can override, see this list of the [13 extensibility points of MVC3](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/04/08/13-asp.net-mvc-extensibility-points-you-have-to-know.aspx).

Also, I forgot to mention initially, but if you are really interested in the guts of MVC, the entire framework is open source (its under the APL) and you can find it [on codeplex.](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That is exactly the kind of depth in an answers i was looking for.

Comment: see my edit for a link to the source, if you *really* want to see what goes on inside MVC.

Answer (score 0):

The controller suffix is considered a convention for MVC (see here for some details on the convention over configuration method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), it has value as it provides a consistent structure for all MVC projects. In addition it describes the function of the class within the MVC pattern.

MVC is very much about convention, if you want something that is more about configuration perhaps take a look at ASP.Net webforms

Answer (score 0):

The folder name is only useful to YOU as a human.  The compiler doesn't care, it all gets compiled into a single DLL, and the folder is irrelevant (although by default it does get put into a namespace with "Controllers").  The folder does not get uploaded to the final site at all.

Because the folder doesn't exist on the server, you can't make the framework assume that because it's in the Controllers folder it's a controller.  It just doesn't work that way, nor is there any way to make it work that way (again, because the Controllers folder does not exist on the server).

The convention of naming things xxxController is to make things easier.  If you don't want to follow the conventsion MVC dictates, then perhaps MVC isn't the right framework for you.  It will only make your life more difficult if you want to fight the flow.

It's like complaining that you don't like naming your C Sharp files with a .cs extension, or that you don't like naming your Webforms forms with an .aspx.